# How to get Old value of a cell in Datagridview after programmatic setting of cell value?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, undo

I am trying to retrieve old value of edited `Datagridview` cell so that I can allow user to undo the changes. The cell value which is edited is done **programmatically** (without typing into the cell). Below is the code I am using for editing the cell value (however the actual implementation is in `LabVIEW`):

```
dataGridView1[1,1].Value = "New Value";
```

I've been using `CellBeginEdit` event to capture old values of a cell if user is typing value in a cell. and it works fine. but does not work for programmatic cell edits.

I tried `CellValidating` Event but does not fire for the programmatic edits.

Will appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just save the value before changing it?

Comment: Yes, that is the option I was looking at finally. I was still expecting to get the old value of a cell no matter how it has changed from `CellValueChanged` event.